# How to get div(s) side by side totaling 100% width

Tags: html, css, padding

I am having an issue that when i float two div(s) (one left, one right) i have this strange padding that i cannot find in my code in the following link you will see my issue. The div on the right (sidebar) has some kind of padding to the right and i cannot figure out how to remove it.
[image]
So my question is: How do i remove the above mentioned padding?

Attached bellow is my HTML code followed by CSS.

```css
    #wrapper {
        width: 80%;
        height: 980px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4%;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .body {
        width: 75%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>sidebar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1>body</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What browser did you take the screenshot with? Once converted to a Stack Snippet we see a different result on Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome, sorry old screenshot, will update now. will reply once updated

Comment: Updated screenshot: http://puu.sh/wiuni/54d3d47eb6.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The borders do not contribute to the width by default on standards compliant browsers.

Either fix this by adjusting the width to account for the borders, or change the box sizing model;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=control

> border-box
>
> The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.
>   Here the dimension is calculated as, width = border + padding + width of the content, and height = border + padding + height of the content.

Adding `box-sizing: border-box;` is a fix, that will make the borders count towards the width.

Doing `width: calc(75% - 2px)` can let you specify what the width should be in a way that is easy to read.

With border-box

```css
    #wrapper {
        width: 80%;
        height: 980px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #wrapper > div {/*direct div descendents of wrapper only*/
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4%;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .body {
        width: 75%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>sidebar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1>body</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

With Width

**Edit:** I wasn't able to successfully create a snippet for width, some more tweaking may be required with the height, clearing the footer, or floating both the body and sidebar in the same direction? or adding content.

A warning about using calc() for the width:

the default border sizes are not standard across browsers. in order to properly specify a width, you will need to declare the size of the border using a cross browser compatible method.

Answer (score 1):

The default box model **adds** the width of borders (and padding) to the width you've specified for an element, so `.body` and `.sidebar` are actually each slightly wider than 25% and 75%, hence they don't fit into one row.

To change the box model so that the width of borders is **included** in the widths you specify, use `box-sizing: border-box`.

E.g.

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;} /* Make all elements use 'border-box' */
```

Here's your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CookieJon/2prnz7m2/)

Here's info about [CSS Box Sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> `box-sizing: border-box` : The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.so when you use of padding or border no affect on width that you defined.

**For Fix:**

> Just add `#wrapper * {box-sizing: border-box;}`

```css
#wrapper {
        width: 80%;
        height: 980px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
.header {
        width: 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
}
    
.navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4%;
        border-style: solid;
}
    
.body {
        width: 75%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
    
.sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
         <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">

    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h1>sidebar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <h1>body</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not padding, its width of the borders I guess. If you remove the borders it will work

```
.body {
        width: 75%;
        height: 80%;
        border: none;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: green;
}

.sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 80%;
        border: none;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was it!

Comment: Do you know of a way that i could keep the borders, like a way so i can set border-width to 2px then just do somthing along lines of width = 75% -2px

Comment: Look up the `calc()` function in CSS. You can do something like: `width: calc(75% - 2px);` from what I remember. @Jason1232

Comment: Use box-sizing:border-box, that way when you set a width it includes border and padding

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, using CSS `float`s makes my HTML and CSS prone to weird overflow/misalignment issues like this. Notice how if I declare the property-value pair `overflow: hidden;` on `#wrapper` they seem to align. That said, the right-hand side border of each still gets truncated. Im able to fix this by including `[box-sizing][1]: border-box;` on the direct descendants of the `#wrapper` child (*i.e.*, using the `#wrapper > *` selector). This property simply ensures that the `border-width` is included along with the usual content and `padding` when specifying `width`s and/or `height`s.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 980px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper > * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.header {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    border-style: solid;
}
.body {
    width: 75%;
    height: 80%;
    border-style: solid;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 80%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>sidebar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <h1>body</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The only part of your answer that solves the problem is changing the box-sizing. Recommending overflow:hidden without explaining what it does is prone for future errors for OP.